# next button of jquery tab not working

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery tab and on next button I want it to move to the next tab

```
    $(".next-tab").click(function () {
       var selected = $("#tab-div").Tabs("option", "selected");
       alert(selected);
    $("#tab-div").Tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
    });


    <div id="tab-div">
    <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#tab1" class="current">New Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">For Companies</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="list-wrap">
    <div id="tab1" class="">
    <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="alltbls creatgrp">
    <tr>
    <td width="239" class="td-left req">Group Name</td>
    <td> <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" class="text" runat="server" TabIndex="1" onchange="ontextchange()"></asp:TextBox>  </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="">
        <table width="70%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" class="alltbls creatgrp">
        <tr>
            <td width="239" class="td-left req">Group Name</td>
            <td> <asp:TextBox ID="txtGroupName" class="text" runat="server" TabIndex="1" onchange="ontextchange()"></asp:TextBox>  </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

On alert I am getting object object instead of the tab index.

Thanks,

Comment: you should really create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pAwMA/) as it reinforce and answerer able to reproduce on the problem you reported.

Comment: Try doing tabs instead of Tabs with a capital T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tabs` should be lowercase - `tabs`.

```
$(".next-tab").click(function () {
    var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");
    alert(selected);
    $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```

Comment: I am getting  
$("#tab-div").tabs is not a function in this line
var selected = $("#tab-div").tabs("option", "selected");

Comment: thanks @Rory McCrossan it is working fine. I am trying to implement that the tab should change on enter key and it is working fine but only once. If i move to the first tab again and then press enter then it is not working. Can u help me with this please

Comment: @asifa It's probably best to start a new question for that one - I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you need to do : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RaaDV/273/)**

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

You must lowercase your "Tabs".And do not forget using "$(your_div).tabs();" at start of your code ;

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```